# SQL Server 2012 Using LAG with ROLLUP To Remove Consecutive Duplicates in Field - Results Reversed

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a query that I wrote that works great using `WITH ROLLUP`. It is 6 columns wide with the last column containing a number representing an order amount. Each of the other 5 columns gets progressively more specific in identifying that order with column 5 being the order number.

The query shows all the totals for any given 'level' of our organization one is interested in. However, I have the requirement to remove duplicate data from the report. There are no duplicate rows, but each of the more general columns has a lot of repeated data in consecutive rows.

The query works fine generating a result like this:

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦ Affiliate Company ¦ Affiliate Name ¦ Customer Company ¦ Customer ¦ Order Number ¦ Total Sales ¦
¦-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------+--------------+-------------¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ Dennis   ¦ 105773       ¦ $111.60     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ Steve    ¦ 105776       ¦ $398.75     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ John     ¦ 104686       ¦ $1,228.10   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Julie    ¦ 105701       ¦ $152.64     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jennifer ¦ 104681       ¦ $5.00       ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jennifer ¦ 105766       ¦ $218.79     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 104684       ¦ $2,500.00   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 104691       ¦ $321.28     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105744       ¦ $739.80     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jean     ¦ 104682       ¦ $3,990.00   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 104688       ¦ $1,328.40   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105699       ¦ $5,112.00   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105711       ¦ $219.10     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105758       ¦ $2,202.50   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105739       ¦ $2,278.04   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105769       ¦ $820.84     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105770       ¦ $797.12     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Dee Dee  ¦ 105702       ¦ $2,244.30   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦
¦ ght               ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦
¦ NULL              ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,668.26  ¦
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

However, when I add LAG to the mix to remove duplicate data I get this:

```
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
¦ Affiliate Company ¦ Affiliate Name ¦ Customer Company ¦ Customer ¦ Order Number ¦ Total Sales ¦ Previous ¦
¦-------------------+----------------+------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+----------¦
¦ NULL              ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,668.26  ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $510.35     ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ Dennis   ¦ 105773       ¦ $111.60     ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ OL                ¦ Brian          ¦ Customer         ¦ Steve    ¦ 105776       ¦ $398.75     ¦ Dennis   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ NULL           ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦ Steve    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ NULL             ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ NULL     ¦ subtotal     ¦ $24,157.91  ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ John     ¦ 104686       ¦ $1,228.10   ¦ NULL     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Julie    ¦ 105701       ¦ $152.64     ¦ John     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jennifer ¦ 104681       ¦ $5.00       ¦ Julie    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jennifer ¦ 105766       ¦ $218.79     ¦ Jennifer ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 104684       ¦ $2,500.00   ¦ Jennifer ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 104691       ¦ $321.28     ¦ Jason    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105744       ¦ $739.80     ¦ Jason    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jean     ¦ 104682       ¦ $3,990.00   ¦ Jason    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 104688       ¦ $1,328.40   ¦ Jean     ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105699       ¦ $5,112.00   ¦ Random   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105711       ¦ $219.10     ¦ Random   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Random   ¦ 105758       ¦ $2,202.50   ¦ Random   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105739       ¦ $2,278.04   ¦ Random   ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105769       ¦ $820.84     ¦ Jason    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Jason    ¦ 105770       ¦ $797.12     ¦ Jason    ¦
¦ ght               ¦ Tom            ¦ Customer         ¦ Dee Dee  ¦ 105702       ¦ $2,244.30   ¦ Jason    ¦
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

You can see all I did was add the "Previous" column and my data is now reversed. My intention is that I would go back and filter out all the consecutive duplicates. However, with the data backwards like this I can't effectively remove duplicates, nor can the result even be read easily. Any thoughts on how to accomplish what I'm looking to do?

My code is as follows:

UPDATE: With the help on sorting, everything fell into place with the following code:

```
WITH Names AS (
SELECT 
Customer.CustomerID
, Customer.LastName + ', ' + Customer.FirstName + ' (' + Customer.Email + ')' AS 'Customer'
FROM
Customer
)
SELECT
CASE WHEN (Affiliate.Company = LAG(Affiliate.Company, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Affiliate.Company) AND GROUPING(Affiliate.Name) < 1) THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN GROUPING(Affiliate.Name) < 1 THEN Affiliate.Company ELSE Affiliate.Company + ' subtotal:' END END AS 'Affiliate Company'
, CASE WHEN (Affiliate.Name = LAG(Affiliate.Name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Affiliate.Company, Affiliate.Name) AND GROUPING(CustomerLevel.Name) < 1) THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN GROUPING(CustomerLevel.Name) < 1 THEN Affiliate.Name ELSE Affiliate.Name + ' subtotal:' END END AS 'Affiliate Name'
, CASE WHEN (CustomerLevel.Name = LAG(CustomerLevel.Name, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Affiliate.Company, Affiliate.Name, CustomerLevel.Name) AND GROUPING(Names.Customer) < 1) THEN NULL ELSE CASE WHEN GROUPING(Names.Customer) < 1 THEN CustomerLevel.Name ELSE CustomerLevel.Name + ' subtotal:' END END AS 'Customer Company'
, Names.Customer AS 'Customer'
, CASE GROUPING(Orders.OrderNumber) WHEN 1 THEN CASE WHEN GROUPING(Affiliate.Company) = 1 THEN 'GRAND TOTAL' ELSE 'subtotal' END ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,Orders.OrderNumber) END AS 'Order Number'
, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,SUM(Orders.OrderSubtotal)),1) AS 'Total Sales'
FROM            Orders INNER JOIN
                         Affiliate ON Orders.AffiliateID = Affiliate.AffiliateID INNER JOIN
                         Customer ON Orders.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                         CustomerLevel ON Customer.CustomerLevelID = CustomerLevel.CustomerLevelID INNER JOIN
                         Names ON Customer.CustomerID = Names.CustomerID
GROUP BY
Affiliate.Company
, Affiliate.Name
, CustomerLevel.Name
, Names.Customer
, Orders.OrderNumber
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
GROUPING(Orders.OrderNumber) < 1
OR
GROUPING(Names.Customer) = 1
OR
GROUPING(Affiliate.Company) = 1
OR
GROUPING(Affiliate.Name) = 1
OR
GROUPING(CustomerLevel.Name) = 1
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN Affiliate.Company IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, Affiliate.Company
, CASE WHEN Affiliate.Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, Affiliate.Name
, CASE WHEN CustomerLevel.Name IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, CustomerLevel.Name
, CASE WHEN Names.Customer IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
, Names.Customer
```

UPDATE: In case anyone is interested, here is the result with all the unnecessary consecutive duplicates removed:

```
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| Affiliate Company | Affiliate Name  |  Customer Company  | Customer | Order Number | Total Sales |
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
| OL                | Brian           | Customer           | Dennis   | 105773       | $111.60     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Steve    | 105776       | $398.75     |
| NULL              | NULL            | Customer subtotal: | NULL     | subtotal     | $510.35     |
| NULL              | Brian subtotal: | NULL               | NULL     | subtotal     | $510.35     |
| WYN-OL subtotal:  | NULL            | NULL               | NULL     | subtotal     | $510.35     |
| ght               | Tom             | Customer           | John     | 104686       | $1,228.10   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Julie    | 105701       | $152.64     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jennifer | 104681       | $5.00       |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jennifer | 105766       | $218.79     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 104684       | $2,500.00   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 104691       | $321.28     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 105744       | $739.80     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jean     | 104682       | $3,990.00   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Random   | 104688       | $1,328.40   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Random   | 105699       | $5,112.00   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Random   | 105711       | $219.10     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Random   | 105758       | $2,202.50   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 105739       | $2,278.04   |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 105769       | $820.84     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Jason    | 105770       | $797.12     |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | Dee Dee  | 105702       | $2,244.30   |
| NULL              | NULL            | Customer subtotal: | NULL     | subtotal     | $24,157.91  |
| NULL              | Tom subtotal:   | NULL               | NULL     | subtotal     | $24,157.91  |
| ght subtotal:     | NULL            | NULL               | NULL     | subtotal     | $24,157.91  |
| NULL              | NULL            | NULL               | NULL     | GRAND TOTAL  | $24,668.26  |
+-------------------+-----------------+--------------------+----------+--------------+-------------+
```

I do know that something like this is often best done in a language other than SQL. However, at this point in the project that is not an option. I either do it in SQL or we have to deal with the 'extra' data.

*Praise http://www.sensefulsolutions.com/2010/10/format-text-as-table.html for table formatting tools!

Comment: Your SELECT statement does not have an ORDER BY clause, so why would you assume that the output order of the rows was stable?  It isn't unless you have an ORDER BY.

Comment: False.  On both counts.  Neither GROUP BY nor ROLLUP require ordering (as hashing, etc. works just fine), but even if they did, SQL  still has ***no*** commitment to return them in that order.  And if ORDER BY didn't change the returned order, then you're doing it wrong, so please update your post with the ORDER BY version.

Comment: Please, please, please don't assume that `GROUP BY` will guarantee order. Just because it *might* sort as a part of grouping does not mean it will group in the same order as you defined, and there is absolutely no guarantee that it has to present them in that order in any case (you may be thinking of SQL Server 2000 behavior, where it wasn't guaranteed either, but it was more reliable). Is the problem just that you meant to use LEAD instead of LAG, or need to order your LAG with DESC on one or more columns? I find it confusing that your LAG is based on four string columns.

Comment: Assuming the `LAG` values are correct they're just presented in the wrong order, then as has been suggested, you need to add a proper ORDER BY clause instead of relying on assumptions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As everyone else has stated already, SQL Server (or any RDBMS for that matter) does not make any guarantees over the output order, unless you specify the required output order using an `ORDER BY` clause in the outer most `SELECT`. If no `ORDER BY` is specified, execution plan changes can change the output order. Even the number of available (= non-busy) processors at the time of query execution can affect the output order.

`GROUP BY` does not require the engine to sort the data. If the data set is big enough, SQL Server will use a Hash-Aggregate instead of a Stream-Aggregate. If that happens the rows will be returned in random order. So again, if you need the rows in a specific order, you need to specify that with `ORDER BY`.

The result of the `LAG()` function is independent of the final row order. It is only affected by the order specified in it's own `OVER()` clause. You can even have multiple `LAG`s using different orders.

That means, any comparison you might want to do between the current row's value and the `LAG`ed value will still be correct.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
WITH Names AS (
SELECT 
Customer.CustomerID
, Customer.LastName + ', ' + Customer.FirstName + ' (' + Customer.Email + ')' AS 'Customer'
FROM
Customer
)
SELECT
Affiliate.Company AS 'Affiliate Company'
, Affiliate.Name AS 'Affiliate Name'
, CustomerLevel.Name AS 'Customer Company'
, Names.Customer as 'Customer'
, CASE GROUPING(Orders.OrderNumber) WHEN 1 THEN 'subtotal' ELSE CONVERT(VARCHAR,Orders.OrderNumber) END AS 'Order Number'
, '$' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,CONVERT(MONEY,SUM(Orders.OrderSubtotal)),1) AS 'Total Sales'
, LAG(Names.Customer, 1) OVER (ORDER BY Affiliate.Company, Affiliate.Name, CustomerLevel.Name, Names.Customer) AS 'Previous'
FROM            Orders INNER JOIN
                         Affiliate ON Orders.AffiliateID = Affiliate.AffiliateID INNER JOIN
                         Customer ON Orders.CustomerID = Customer.CustomerID INNER JOIN
                         CustomerLevel ON Customer.CustomerLevelID = CustomerLevel.CustomerLevelID INNER JOIN
                         Names ON Customer.CustomerID = Names.CustomerID
GROUP BY
Affiliate.Company
, Affiliate.Name
, CustomerLevel.Name
, Names.Customer
, Orders.OrderNumber
WITH ROLLUP
HAVING
GROUPING(Orders.OrderNumber) < 1
OR
GROUPING(Names.Customer) = 1
OR
GROUPING(Affiliate.Company) = 1
OR
GROUPING(Affiliate.Name) = 1
OR
GROUPING(CustomerLevel.Name) = 1
ORDER BY     
    GROUPING(Affiliate.Company),
    GROUPING(Affiliate.Name),
    GROUPING(CustomerLevel.Name),
    GROUPING(Names.Customer)
```